# How does Cloud Foundry memory limit work?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

Lets say I have started 2 instances of my application and each is assigned with 1GB memory limit. I wonder what would happen if one of my instances has used up all the memory. Would it be unresponsive ? Or would a new instance be created as replacement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer lies in the CF documentation:

"Memory Limit: The maximum amount of memory that each instance of your application is allowed to consume. If an instance exceeds this limit, the instance is restarted. If the instance has to be restarted too often, it is terminated. To prevent this we recommend being generous with your memory limit."

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html

If you'd like to autoscale the application, there are ways to script that based on triggers, instantiating new instances of your application if conditions you set are met.  Note, this is not out of the box functionality of CF, yet.

Comment: How to change the memory limitation? I see my app can use only 300MB out of 1 GB on CF

Comment: I see this - http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.htmlMemory Limit: The maximum amount of memory that each instance of your app can consume. If an instance exceeds this limit, Cloud Foundry restarts the instance.
Note: Initially, Cloud Foundry immediately restarts any instances that exceed the memory limit. If an instance repeatedly exceeds the memory limit in a short period of time, Cloud Foundry delays restarting the instance.

Comment: @Chris would you happen to know the root cause? 1 instance with 1GB works fine, but when boosting to 6-8 instances my application crashes due to memory limit.